# Dump table with portions MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 databases on the same server, 2nd is "newer". I need to copy values from Table1 from 1st db to Table1 from 2nd db.

Second Table1 has a bit different structure, so i wanted to generate insert statements from 1st table and do some convertation, and after that to insert data to 2nd Table1.

But have here a problem. The table has about 1.7million records, and the dump of the insert statements is more than 3GB. SSMS doesnt want to open such big file.

So the question is how to dump that data in some portions, to few files, so i will be able to load them to ssms one by one ?

Thank you

PS All the data are for the developers only, its not a production database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create scripts of INSERT statements? Why not just INSERT from one table to another using 3-part-naming.

```
INSERT Database2.dbo.Table1 (column list)
SELECT column list
FROM Database1.dbo.Table1
```

You can do any transformation you need in the SELECT, for example, if a column has changed from an INT to NVARCHAR(2) you could use `CAST(MyIntColumn AS NVARCHAR(2))`.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are in different server you can develop a simple SSIS package to transfer the data

The SSIS package should have a Data Flow Task with 1st db as source and 2nd db as destination.You can also have a Derived column task in the middle for data conversion

Comment: OP states that the databases are on the same server.

Comment: Even if they are on the same server you could use SSIS to do this